# eclipselink JPA: combining @MappedSuperclass with @Cacheable

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, inheritance, jpa, eclipselink

If I annotate a mapped superclass with `@cachable(false)`, like so...

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Cacheable(false)
public abstract class MySuperclass {
   ...
}
```

... will all subclass entities be non-cacheable by default?

I guess what I'm more generally asking is: do entities inherit annotations from super classes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the `@Cacheable` setting is [inherited by the subclasses](http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/Cacheable) and can be overridden by them.

Comment: Great, thanks @kostja. I also had to add the `<shared-cache-mode>DISABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>` property to my persistence unit (in `persistence.xml`). After that, works a treat.